# Test app with questns number. Jump from questn to questn

Tags: android

How can I make something like a test app with it's questions numbers at the bottom (http://prntscr.com/dg4lr9)? When I press a certain number that question is being opened also it's values need to be stored, like the marked answers.

I am sort of newbie and I am not looking for the best approach which is going to serve me with good performance. All I need is a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the best approach is using sqlite database, and store the questions there.